# Can't get output from Tesseract command run through os.system

Tags: python, subprocess, tesseract, popen, os.system

I've created a function which loops over images and gets the orientation from the image with the `tesseract` library. The code looks like this:

```
def fix_incorrect_orientation(pathName):
    for filename in os.listdir(pathName):
        tesseractResult = str(os.system('tesseract ' + pathName + '/' + filename + ' -  -psm 0'))
        print('tesseractResult: ' + tesseractResult)
        regexObj = re.search('([Orientation:]+[\s][0-9]{1})',tesseractResult)
        if regexObj:
            orientation = regexObj.groups(0)[0]
            print('orientation123: ' + str(orientation))
        else:
            print('Not getting in the Regex.')
```

The result from the variable `tesseractResult` is always `0` though. But in the terminal I will get the following result from the command:

```
Orientation: 3
Orientation in degrees: 90
Orientation confidence: 19.60
Script: 1
Script confidence: 21.33
```

I've tried catching the output from the `os.system` in multiple ways, such as with `Popen` and `subprocess` but without any succes. It seems that I can't catch the output from the `tesseract` library.
So, how exactly should I do this?

Thanks,
Yenthe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally 10 minutes after asking the question I found a way.. First import commands:

```
import commands
```

And then the following code will do the trick:

```
def fix_incorrect_orientation(pathName):
    for filename in os.listdir(pathName):
        tesseractResult = str(commands.getstatusoutput('tesseract ' + pathName + '/' + filename + ' -  -psm 0'))
        print('tesseractResult: ' + tesseractResult)
        regexObj = re.search('([Orientation:]+[\s][0-9]{1})',tesseractResult)
        if regexObj:
            orientation = regexObj.groups(0)[0]
            print('orientation123: ' + str(orientation))
        else:
            print('Not getting in the Regex.')
```

This will pass the command around with the `commands` library and the output is caught thanks to `getstatusoutput` from the `commands` library.

Comment: don't use `str()` unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian what exactly is so bad / wrong about doing this then?

Comment: if you have to ask; you shouldn't use it in the first place. It is a hallmark of a sloppy code.

Comment: I actually never knew this. So I'm better of using it without str()? Do you have any link to an article that explains what is so bad to using the str()?

Comment: Using (ofthen unnecessary or even harmful) code without understanding what it does is called ["cargo-cult programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)